# Using java Aspectj/Annotation to log http request in Spring Boot

Tags: rest, annotations, spring-boot, aspectj, servlet-filters

I have created an Aspectj that is triggered when methods are annotated with @AuditLog.

The purpose is to log all the request parameters and body. The issue that I'm having is that inside the Aspectj the InputStream has already been consumed, probably by spring when creating the @RequestBody parameters in the rest method.

I don't want to use a filter with a wrapper since I want the least invasive modification to the actual code and also I only need to log certain methods.

Can this be done inside the Aspectj?

---

Edit. More Info added.

I wanted to do this in The AspectJ because I don't need to log all the methods, I also need to read information from the properties file and added to the log message. This log has to be saved to a queue for later processing.

A could use a wrapper inside the AspectJ but the InsputStream has already been consumed.

Comment: The least invasive way is a filter as that doesn't require any code change and heck Spring provides you with one already. See also https://mdeinum.wordpress.com/2015/07/01/spring-framework-hidden-gems/#more-155. Either way you cannot read the body twice so you will always need to use a wrapper of some sorts because else you end up consuming it either prematurely for logging or you are not able to log because it is already consumed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also need to put a trace_id in the log message and send it to a queue. This is why I want to do it in an AspectJ.

I could use a wrapper in the AspectJ, but the InputStream has already been consumed when it gets there.

Comment: Correct and thus it will never work this way as you are required to wrap the incoming request. Also adding the trace_id I would do using the MDC and use a placeholder in the log message for it (you could fill this using another filter) this would make everything transparant and you don't have to change code only configure a couple of things.

Comment: Thank you @M.Deinum. Since I only needed to log some methods and read Annotation attributes I ended up using a filter and creating a Request Wrapper.